# Official arguments of TTD about birth place of Hanuman

Tags: hanuman, resource, tirupati

TTD made an official announcement about [birth place of Hanuman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28700/was-lord-hanuman-born-in-sumeru-where-is-that-place-is-it-renamed-recently) on (today) 21-April-2020. [1](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/hyderabad/andhra-pradesh-lord-hanuman-was-born-in-tirumala-ttd-to-announce-today/articleshow/82173020.cms) [2](https://www.news18.com/news/india/anjanadri-in-andhra-is-lord-hanumans-birthplace-tirumala-tirupati-devasthanams-3664244.html) [3](https://www.gulte.com/political-news/81868/ttd-provides-evidence-for-the-birthplace-of-hanuman) [4](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/anjanadri-hillock-is-lord-hanuman-birthplace-tirumala-tirupati-devasthanams-1793558-2021-04-21)

TTD announced that **Tirumala** is the birth place of Hanuman.

Although there are some statements in news and blogs regarding evidence and research work. I want to read the official document of research work that proves that Hanuman was born in Tirumala.

Where can I find the official document containing scriptural references and the analysis that leads to such conclusion?

Comment: There’s an anjanadri near Hampi too. Hope they clear the difference between hampi’s anjanadri and that of Andhra.

Comment: It's all political. A strategy to pit Hindus against each other. AP government is doing rampant conversion with christians(christian chief minister's relative) infuriating TTD and other Temple trusts and attack on temples being a common news.

Comment: @Archit yes Hamphi has been considered as birthplace of Lord Hanuman. This recent political stint by TTD(Read AP christian government) is to divide Hindus. Already in AP temples are being vandalized and missionaries are converting Hindus. Even christian chief minister's relative have infuriated TTD and other temple trusts.

Comment: @RishX I had read about their burning temples and beheading idols. Don’t tell me to read it’ll unnecessarily increase my blood pressure. The only solution for these miscreants is send the army into AP and declare presidents rule. Wonder if citizens can file a petition for presidents rule. You mean Hampi is original or AP is original? Why would TTD itself want to divide us. Wouldn’t the Govt be doing that?

Comment: @Archit I can't get that picture of a Priest crying and holding head of a broken murti of Sri Rama 's idol out of my head. Sadly, nothing is going to happen since in India,secularism means supressing Hindus and appeasing abrahamics. Even Indian courts work against Hindus,Hindus can't manage their own temples. As for TTD, recently there was controversy about how the relative of christian cm jagan was made chair person but nothing happened. They are christians who keep Hindu names.

Comment: @Archit therefore even TTD is not what you think it to be. Even jagan's father (when he was cm from congres)was trying hard to destroy sanctity of Tirupati temple, his unnatural death lead people to believe it was Sri Venkateswara's punishment. As for Lord Hanuman's birthplace,I don't think Tirupati was even a candidate before. Yes Sri Rama worship is extremely popular in telugu states but it is traditionally believed that Lord Hanuman was born in Karnataka(where even Kishkindha exists).

Comment: Oh that panditji’s photo was heart wrenching. North India is plagued by ms and south India by Christians. Ramaji worship is popular because of bhadrachalam. Lord Venkateswara should blast all these fellows. Have you heard of Agniveer which helps getting converted people back?

Comment: @RishX and Hanuman, both, also have a look at this person he’s from AP and very good for dharma and exposing these fellows: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=guWfXe5uZQg. Will delete comment

Comment: @Archit that's Vinod from string right? I have been following him for quite some time now. Have you seen his video where he interviews AP MLA who said 25% people of AP are already christian.Here https://youtu.be/YQWHd6MKSTgI think there is another organization by the name of Shiva Shakthi who are exposing missionary activities. All of there videos are in telugu but I know this much, you can recommend it to people from AP

Comment: @Archit not just agniveer, ISKCON,vhp and other local organisations are working as well.

Comment: I have answered the question here:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/893/why-is-lord-hanuman-known-as-pavan-putra-hanuman/50961#50961

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer [here from official TTD website](http://news.tirumala.org/ttd-declares-anjanadri-as-birth-place-of-anjaneya-with-evidences/).

> **Some excerpts from the evidences he has put forth to media-**

> In the Valmiki Ramayana, from Sundarakanda episode in the Shlolas from 81-83 of 35th Sarga, it was clearly mentioned that since Hanuman was born to Anjana on these sacred mountains after a penance, He attained the name Anjaneya while the Hillock got the name Anjanadri.

> Rock inscriptions at Srivari temple of 1491 and 1545, both mention the Anjanadri as birth place of Anjaneya.

> Vyasa Mahabharata, Vanaparva, 147 Chapter, Valmiki Ramayana-Kishkinda Kanda – 66th Sarga (Chapter), Shiva Puranam, Shata Rudra Samhita-Chapter 20, Brahmanda Puranam-Sri Venkatachala Mahatyam-Thirtha Khandam-Chapter 1, Skanda Purana, Vaishnava Khand-1.38, Epigraphica Indica, Vol VI, page 323.

> Anjanadri Mahatyam…a book available at London Library clearly explains Anjanadri as the birthplace of Hanuman.

> He also referred to Kamba Ramayanam-Kishkindakandam, Hamsa Dootam etc.which also explained the same.